# cache request miss graphite sitespeed.io

Tags: cache, graphite

I want to send data from sitespeed.io to graphite using this command `sitespeed.io -u http://www.sitespeed.io --graphiteHost localhost -m 5 --graphiteNamespace sitespeed -b firefox -n 3`

I think the data are send to graphite but i can not visualize anything [image]

when i check the cache.log file I found this

```
Request-Cache miss [eea168638b98656710080]
Mon Nov 09 01:58:37 2015 :: Data-Cache miss    [fb044adb75fb94bd892a5]
Mon Nov 09 02:18:06 2015 :: Request-Cache miss [eea16869e132ac6567144ab0080]
Mon Nov 09 02:18:06 2015 :: Data-Cache miss [063c48a3f48d8b2f5a1a947]
Mon Nov 09 02:18:17 2015 :: Request-Cache miss [02eb2368cb10aef607c9e1051f]
Mon Nov 09 02:18:17 2015 :: Data-Cache miss [b78b8cda4736cf17e9fde3]
Mon Nov 09 02:18:17 2015 :: CarbonLink creating a new socket for ('127.0.0.1', None)
Mon Nov 09 02:18:17 2015 :: CarbonLink cache-query request for sitespeed.http.sitespeed_io.slash.requests.http.sitespeed_io.slash.timings.receive returned 1 datapoints
Mon Nov 09 02:18:20 2015 :: Request-Cache miss [02eb236b10aef051f]
Mon Nov 09 02:18:20 2015 :: Data-Cache miss [b78b8cd74df7e9fde3]
```

Have anybody idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

If someone want to know more about this issue you could see this link https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/issues/467